# MSSQL - ODBC - PHP - Get max Value of a Column ID

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, max

I want read out a max value of a column (ID).(of a MSSQL Server over ODBC)

```
$res=odbc_exec("SELECT Users FROM ID "); 
$a=odbc_fetch_array($res); 
print_r($a);
```

But its wrong .
Its frustating
Have anyone a idea for it ?

Thanks for your Time.

Greetings

Comment: select max(ID) as maximum from Users; ??

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to get the maximum ID of column then

```
 select max(column) from tbl;
```

Comment: I have edited the select command and got this

Warning: Wrong parameter count for odbc_exec() in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\web\register.php on line 7

Warning: odbc_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid ODBC result resource in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\web\register.php on line 8

Line 7 is $res=odbc_exec("SELECT Users FROM ID ");
Line 9 is  $Configuration_ODBC_Server

Comment: plz show me the screen shot of your code so i can understand better and at least put your current query here plz